# Windows Error Reporting and IIS7 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, windows

In a windows webservere I'm trying to get a memory dump of a failing IIS 7 worker process (w3wp.exe) with no avail.

In the Event Viewer I get the following.

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bd0eb
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba21eeb
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005c22
Faulting process id: 0x1cac
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc23419da54772
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: b54ec4f8-8fa4-11e0-ab62-005056810035
```

Even if I've configured LocalDumps for WER, and specifically for w3wp.exe in the registry. I get another event telling me that there is a report here: *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_cdb8af6deb381574fe9fb0dc9aa3edaad59acd5f_cab_4fbf9b53*

It contains the following files:

- WERD931.tmp.appcompat.txt
- WERDFE9.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
- WER99EF.tmp.WERDataCollectionFailure.txt

The "depressing one" is the WERDataCollectionFailure that says:

> Heap dump generation failed: 0x8007012b Mini dump generation failed: 0x8007001f

After many tries, lots of msdn documentation and many failed google search. I'm out of ideas on how to get a dump here.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to make WER work?

Thank you in advance for your time reading this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look to use [Debug Diag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931370/en-us) to capture a memory dump, here's the [whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4a2fbd0d-0635-440c-a08b-ed81bdbb5960). The other way is using [Debugging tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) and using the command:

```
c:\debuggers\adplus.vbs -crash -pn w3wp.exe -o c:\dumps
```

Comment: Debug Diag does not work with IIS7 in a 64bits machine. I must say that in the end a 2008 R2 server plus not using ASP.NET4 (using ASP.NET2) configuration made the WER work. Also I had to downgrade the WinDBG version because there were two CLRs loaded .NET2 and .NET4 and newer WinDBG try to work only on the newest CLR they find in the dump.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the adplus.vbs tip. I didn't want to follow that path because every day we recycle our workers. So everyday I need to re-attach to the workers.

Answer (score 1):

The error codes in the WERDataCollectionFailure.txt file indicate ERROR_GEN_FAILURE causing ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY.  The ERROR_GEN_FAILURE is "a device attached to the system is not functioning" (pretty general; lives up to its codename).

You will need to look in the event log for another error related to that to see what is happening in more detail.